# Print content in modal popup when popup is shown, but print body if modal popup is hidden

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm using the following CSS to make a modal popup printable but there is one problem. The problem is that since the CSS is added to the page, only the modal popup is printable but not the rest of the page content.

What I want is that when the modal popup is visible (triggered by a button click) then only modal content is printable, but when modal is not visible, only page content should be printable.

```
@media print {
    body * { visibility: hidden; }
    #search-result, #search-result * { visibility: visible; }
    #search-result{ position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; }
}
```

**update**

Thanks for the hint! Here's what I did.

css

```
.print { visibility: visible; }
.no-print { visibility: hidden; }
```

js

```
$('#search-result').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $('body').addClass('print').removeClass('no-print');
    $('#search-result').addClass('no-print').removeClass('print');
});

$('#search-result').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $('body').addClass('no-print').removeClass('print');
    $('#search-result').addClass('print').removeClass('no-print');
});
```

Comment: Is it feasible to add a class to the body when the modal is showing? That way you could target it differently depending on the class it had.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe using a class for hiding the parts of the page you dont want to print could make it easier.

Use this kind of CSS rules

```
@media print {
  .no-print {
    visiblity: hidden;
  }
}
```

And the event handler for the button that shows the modal popup might add the `no-print` class to every element of the page that's not the popup itself. You might want to wrap the whole page in a div to make this easier, and the popup should be outside this wrapper.

When the popup is closed you assing the `no-print` class to the modal popup and remove it from the rest of the page.

If you think wrapping the whole page in a div just to do this is too obstrusive, place the modal popup as a child of the body element, and when you want to print just the popup add the `no-print` class to every child element of the body that's not the popup. When you close the popup make the reverse operation, only the popup should have the `no-print` class, and all the resting childs of the body element shoudln't.